# Rails DB rake tasks run but never exit

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

When I run any of the `rake db` tasks that Rails provides, they run successfully but never exit. I have to CTRL+C to quit the task. I've tested running it for over 8 hours and the problem persists.

Here's the output if I run `rake db:migrate --trace`:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
_
```

Like I said, everything runs as expected, but it hangs after `db:schema:dump`.

I'm using the following:

- Mac OS X 10.7.1 (Lion)
- Ruby 1.9.2p290
- Rails 3.1.0
- MySQL 5.5.14
- mysql2 gem 0.3.7

I'll also note that this is a base Rails app with no gems/code added. I can replicate with `rails new testapp -d mysql` then `rake db:create` or `bundle exec rake db:create`.

Has anyone run into this problem or know what I can do to further troubleshoot?

Comment: SQLite runs normally. It looks like this is a MySQL only problem.

Comment: I'm using mysql2 version 0.3.7.

Comment: `brew update` only downloads updated formulas - it does not build new versions. `brew upgrade` would build new versions. If you did run update, I doubt that's what fixed your problem...

Comment: Please add your fix as an answer to this question and accept it so it's marked as closed.

Comment: @ShaunChapman Since your question got some up-votes, I'd suggest putting your solution into an answer, and then marking that answer as correct (it's okay to answer your own question). That way, the question no longer shows up in the "Unanswered" timeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

First, I tried uninstalling the version of MySQL that was installed using the official binary then reinstalling using Homebrew. That did nothing.

I then ran brew update, restarted MySQL, and tried again. Eureka! It worked.

The culprit seems to have been a bug in an older version of one of the following:

```
libiconv
glib
gtk+
```

Those were the only formulas that were updated.

Answer (score 0):

same thing happen with me also but don't worry, i tried out bundle update after this i never face this issue.